# find divisors and their divisors and so on to certain depth

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, integer, division

for example for depth 2 if number is

```
18
level 1: 1 2 3 6 9 18
level 2: 1 1 2 1 3 1 2 3 6 1 3 9 1 2 3 6 9 18
```

if algorithm for finding single divider of number is following

```
static Integer [] divider(int n) {
    List<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer [] result;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n/2; i++) {
       if (n%i == 0)
           resultList.add(i);
    }
    resultList.add(n);
    result = resultList.toArray(new Integer[resultList.size()]);

    return result;
}
```

i am not sure how the loops should be

```
for(int i=1;i<depth;i++){ 
divisors(n);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static Integer [] divider(int n, int level) {
    List<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer [] result;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n/2; i++) {
      if (n%i == 0) {
           if(level > 1){
               Integer [] divList = divider(i, level-1);
               for(Integer div : divList) {
                   resultList.add(div);
               }
           }
           else
               resultList.add(i);
      }
    }
    resultList.add(n);
    result = resultList.toArray(new Integer[resultList.size()]);

    return result;
  }
```

Above is a recursive solution to your question. Basically, what it does is recursively calls your divider function and keeps track of it's current "level". If the number it's calculating is at a level above 1, it's divisors are calculated and added to resultList as well. If not, it only adds the divisor itself to resultList. This way you don't need to set up any messy looping structure or reuse any code.